# Preventing derived SplEnum (Enum) class from being instantiated in PHP

Tags: php

I am deriving `SplEnum` class in PHP to make my class *behave* like enum, however I found that its constructor is not private.
My understanding of Enumeration is that Enumeration values are supposed to be **fixed** and should have predefined values,so this SplEnum class should not be instantiated.

I have tried to prevent instantiation by making the constructor `final` and throwing Exception internally.
 Here's my code snippet.

```
final class UserType extends \SplEnum{

const __default = self::UNKNOWN;

const UNKNOWN = 0;

const STUDENT = 1;
const STARTUP = 2;
const JURY = 3;
const MENTOR = 4;
const ADMIN = 5;
const SUPERADMIN = 6;

// Here's my thought on how the instantiation could be prevented
public final function __construct(){
    throw new Exception('This class is supposed to be Enum, cannot instantiate this class');
}


public static function isValidUserTypeKey($name,$strict = false){}


public static function isValidUserTypeValue($value) {}


}
```

Is this the *correct* way or there could be better implementation ways?

Thanks.